# Why include the pronoun "lo" in "Avrei dovuto immaginarlo che ..."?

Tags: difference

> Avrei dovuto **immaginarlo** che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli.
>
> {vs}: Avrei dovuto **immaginare** che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli.

Q1. I wonder why you need to use the pronoun "lo" here. Does it serve as a placeholder object that is similar to: "I found **it** difficult **to do** ..."?

Q2. Is it wrong to use the reflexive "immaginar**mi**" or "immaginar**melo**" instead? If so, why?

Comment: You don't need the pronoun "lo". You can simply say "Avrei dovuto immaginare che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli" and that would be standard Italian. This phenomenon, called "ridondanza pronominale", is typical of oral speech and it's done to achieve more emphasis on the direct object "che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli".

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the pronoun *lo*; and, yes, it could be *mi*.

- Avrei dovuto immaginare che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli
- Avrei dovuto immaginarlo che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli
- Avrei dovuto immaginarmi che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli
- Avrei dovuto immaginarmelo che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli
- Mi sarei dovuto immaginare che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli
- Me lo sarei dovuto immaginare che vi sareste fatti degli scrupoli

The first sentence is formal and I'm ready to bet nobody would use it in normal speech. In the second sentence there's a bit more emphasis on “immaginare”; in the third one the emphasis is more on the subject, like in the final sentence.

This can be called a “[redundant pronoun](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali-ridondanti-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/)” that, while being frowned upon by school teachers, has been a feature of Italian since the 14th century (for instance in Boccaccio). I would have no problem in writing any of the sentences above (except the first one) in order to reproduce speech or thought.